# Conditional Expectation And Covariance with Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

For any two random variables X and Y, the covariance is defined as Cov(X, Y ) = E [X − E[X]] [Y − E[Y ]].
• If E [Y |X = x] = x, show that Cov(X, Y ) = E [X − E[X]]2
My approach is that
Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)*E(Y)
If X=Y then maybe the proof becomes true. But I am unable to prove it.
The meaning of  E [Y |X = x] = x Expectation of Y given X=x is x but how can I use this to prove the solution?

Comment: The meaning of $E[Y|X=x]=x$ is that the $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable $E[Y|X]$ can be written as $f(X)$ and this $f(x)$ is just $x$ (please look up the Doob-Dynkin lemma). Then $E[Y|X]=X$. Can you now proceed ?

Comment: You were given a definition for covariance.  Your approach should *not* be to use a different one.

Answer (score 1):

> For any two random variables $X$ and $Y$, the covariance is defined as $$Cov(X, Y ) = E\big[(X − E[X]) (Y − E[Y ])\big]$$

Use *this* definition.

> If $E [Y \mid X = x] = x$, show that $Cov(X, Y ) = E\big[(X − E[X])^2\big]$

You shall also need the Tower Rule (or Law of Iterated Expectation). Here's the easy one to get you started.

$$\begin{align}Cov(X, Y ) & = E\big[(X − E[X]) (Y − E[Y ])\big]\\&=E\big[(X − E[X]) (Y − E[E[Y\mid X] ])\big]\\&=E\big[(X − E[X]) (Y − E[X])\big]\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

The next is a little more complicated, but not too much.  Give it a try...